# Displaying SubCells inside UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to display child cells inside UITableViewCell. I have two arrays containing groupname and groupid. I am able to display the groupname in a tableview with custom TableViewCell by using below code.

```
 NSArray *groupIdArr;
    NSArray *groupNameArr;

groupNameArr (
    ANTISERA,
    CLIA,
    COAGULATION,
    CONFIRMATORY,
    ELISA,
    IMMUNOLOGY,
    MISC,
    RAPID
)

groupIdArr (
    20,
    21,
    22,
    23,
    19,
    31,
    29,
    18
)


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [groupIdArr count];
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ProductGroupTableViewCell";

    ProductGroupTableViewCell *cell = (ProductGroupTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProductGroupTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.productGroupNameLbl.text = [groupNameArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        NSString *saveGroupId = [groupIdArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:saveGroupId forKey:@"SavedGroupId"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *productListVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ProductsListViewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:productListVC animated:YES];


}
```

[image]

When user clicks on the TableViewCell user can see product list related to the selected groupid like below and he can select the products.

[image]

After selecting the products user will be pressing done button to go back to the previous view where he can see the selected products below to the groupname. I am carrying the selected product names in NSMutableArray to previous view. But i am unable to figure out how to show the below output.

I tried a lot to find a solution but no luck. Any help will be really appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use UIView for showing subcell inside cell. create UIView programtically. add this view inside cell whenever you require and reload that particular cell and change height according to your require height... and you good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this demo, you will find your solution.

[SideMenu Demo](https://github.com/PinkyPD/SideMenu)

Comment: download this, and you have to change bit code. And you got your desire result. just developed demo for you. let me know if you need any help.